# is there a way to remove a contact in android using adb shell command?

Tags: shell, adb

I would like to know if there is another way in removing or deleting a specific contact in android using adb shell command. what I tried so far is `adb shell "am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE content://contacts/people/<contact-id>"` but its returning `Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=content: }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=content: flg=0x10000000 }`. Please advice if there are any alternatives from the intent that i am using.

Comment: You should refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613836/delete-contact-via-adb/64770186#64770186)